# Change table bgcolor if both values are equal

Tags: php, algorithm, html-table

I've been doing a web app where it retrieves all of my picked lotto ticket combinations and its corresponding winning combinations. Here it is how it works / my step-by-step work:

1. Retrieval will be the winning combinations table from database
2. After retrieving the Lotto ID from the winning combinations table, it will use it as an ID to find my own picked lotto ticket combinations
   **Here's where the logical error starts**
3. Comparing the first retrieved picked lotto combination to each winning combination. (First Picked combination is equals to first winning combination 1, and so on..)

```php
if($Picked1 == $Win1 || $Picked1 == $Win2 || $Picked1 == $Win3 || $Picked1 == $Win4 ||$Picked1 == $Win5 || $Picked1 == $Win6){
                    echo "<tr><td>$Win1</td>
                      <td>$Win2</td>
                      <td>$Win3</td>
                      <td>$Win4</td>
                      <td>$Win5</td>
                      <td>$Win6</td>
                      <td bgcolor = '#008000'>$Picked1</td>
                      <td>$Picked2</td>
                      <td>$Picked3</td>
                      <td>$Picked4</td>
                      <td>$Picked5</td>
                      <td>$Picked6</td></tr>";
```

**Current Output (with logical error)**

If there are more than one combinations from picked lotto that matches the lotto winning combinations it repeats the same row to the next.

For example: if there are 4 picked lotto combinations that matches the winning combinations then it will be repeated 4 times (4 table rows):

Here's the image of my current output:

[image]

**Objective Output**

What I want is to fix the repetition of printing rows and mark the table cell if the picked lotto combination matches the winning combinations. Printing one row with its picked lotto combinations and make the bgcolor of cell green if it is matched to its corresponding winning lotto combination.

**Question**

How can I fix my algorithm? or is my algorithm is wrong from the start?

Here's my full code: https://pastebin.com/4gN9zqZZ

Comment: Don't post off-site links to your code. You need to add all the relevant code into the question itself (copy/paste). If that link changes/gets removed, this question will be useless for future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in each statement you repeatedly echo **TDs**. Thus it gets duplicated. What you should do instead is to have it only once in according if statement as follows:

```
    echo "<tr><td>$Win1</td>
                  <td>$Win2</td>
                  <td>$Win3</td>
                  <td>$Win4</td>
                  <td>$Win5</td>
                  <td>$Win6</td>";
    if($Picked1 == $Win1 || $Picked1 == $Win2 || $Picked1 == $Win3 || $Picked1 == $Win4 ||$Picked1 == $Win5 || $Picked1 == $Win6){
                  echo "<td bgcolor = '#008000'>$Picked1</td>";
    else{
         echo "<td>$Picked1</td>";
    }
    if($Picked2 == $Win1 || $Picked2 == $Win2 || $Picked2 == $Win3 || $Picked2 == $Win4 ||$Picked2 == $Win5 || $Picked2 == $Win6){
                  echo "<td bgcolor = '#008000'>$Picked2</td>";
    else{
         echo "<td>$Picked2</td>";
    }
    if($Picked3 == $Win1 || $Picked3 == $Win2 || $Picked3 == $Win3 || $Picked3 == $Win4 ||$Picked3 == $Win5 || $Picked3 == $Win6){
                  echo "<td bgcolor = '#008000'>$Picked3</td>";
    else{
         echo "<td>$Picked3</td>";
    }
            //And so on...
             echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Thanks, but It only prints the table cells that matches the winning combinations, example: if two values matches the winning combinations it will only print two table cells in a table row, not printing the other 4 table cells. plus it prints extra table cells making it other rows have a 7 table cells instead of 6.. How can we fix this?

Comment: I am not sure I understand you correctly.  In the code I gave above it states that if the value doesn't match the winning combination then print normal cell : **echo "<td>$Picked3</td>";**. That should work. Am I missing something?

Comment: LOL, sorry. I tried to copy paste the code you gave and now it fixed all my problems. thank you so much bro :D I just placed every else statement in each of every if statement (like the one you provided above).

Comment: Happy to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

- Use arrays to store values and run a loop if you are performing same repetitive check.

**Code:**

```
    <?php

    $winning_combinations = [$Win1,$Win2,$Win3,$Win4,$Win5,$Win6];

    while ($Row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($Picked_Lotto_Query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $picked_db_values = [];
        $picked_db_values[] = $Row2['First_Combination'];
        $picked_db_values[] = $Row2['Second_Combination'];
        $picked_db_values[] = $Row2['Third_Combination'];
        $picked_db_values[] = $Row2['Fourth_Combination'];
        $picked_db_values[] = $Row2['Fifth_Combination'];
        $picked_db_values[] = $Row2['Sixth_Combination'];    

        foreach($picked_db_values as $each_index => $each_combination){
            echo "<tr>
                    <td>$Win1</td>
                    <td>$Win2</td>
                    <td>$Win3</td>
                    <td>$Win4</td>
                    <td>$Win5</td>
                    <td>$Win6</td>";

                $combination_present = in_array($each_combination,$winning_combinations);//store it instead of checking in every iteration
                foreach($picked_db_values as $comb_index => $print_each_comb){
                    if($combination_present && $each_index === $comb_index){
                        echo "<td class='correct_combination'>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<td>";
                    }                
                    echo $print_each_comb;
                    echo "</td>";
                }
            }

            echo "</tr>";
        }
 }
```

In your **style.css**, just write,

```
.correct_combination{
      background-color:#008000;
}
```